# How to get distinct querysets from a set of querysets in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 Django models - DJs and Songs.

```
class DJ(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField()

class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(DJ, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    release = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    duplicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'm trying to get sets of all the songs with the same name for a particular DJ.

This is how I'm doing that

```
for dj in DJ.objects.all():
    song_group_list = []
    dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj)
    for song in dj_song_list:
        song_group = dj_song_list.filter(name=song.name).order_by('song_id')
        if len(song_group) > 1:
            if song_group not in song_group_list:
                song_group_list.append(song_group)
    for group in song_group_list:
        print group
```

This outputs duplicate sets with the same queryset results.

```
[<Song: Ping Pong>, <Song: Ping Pong>, <Song: Ping Pong>]
[<Song: Everybody Is In The Place>, <Song: Everybody Is In The Place>, <Song: Everybody Is In The Place>]
[<Song: Jumper>, <Song: Jumper>, <Song: Jumper>]
[<Song: Man With The Red Face>, <Song: Man With The Red Face>, <Song: Man With The Red Face>, <Song: Man With The Red Face>, <Song: Man With The Red Face>, <Song: Man With the Red Face>]
[<Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>]
[<Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>]
```

How can I get distinct querysets for the above problem?

Comment: can you explain what you want actually ?

Comment: @Kasra My DJ model has songs with duplicate names (but other fields are different). I'm trying to get the sets of songs with the same names for a particular DJ.

Comment: can you add your dj model to your question pls?

Comment: @Kasra I've added my models to the question.

Comment: I Add an answer but i dont got your mean about distinct queryset ! can you show me what you expect by code ? or give me more explain ! **also remember that always have a complete describe about your problem **!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of `append` method because, at first you get all os songlist then order and append it to `song_list` so you must replace the current list with ordered list :

so change your code to :

```
for dj in DJ.objects.all():
    song_group_list = []
    dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj)
    for song in dj_song_list:
        song_group = dj_song_list.filter(name=song.name).order_by('song_id')
        if len(song_group) > 1 and (song_group not in song_group_list):
                song_group_list=song_group
    for group in song_group_list:
        print group
```